# C#, задание графа

Tags: c#, графы

Необходимо написать приложение на C#, позволяющее пользователю задать метрический граф (все ребра ориентированы в какую-либо сторону и имеют длину, бывают кратные ребра, то есть несколько ребер между одной и той же парой вершин, бывают петли, то есть ребро из вершины в себя), то есть отмечать на плоскости точки, соединять некоторые из них и указывать длины ребер. На выходе должен получаться файл, в котором указано:

1. Размер рабочей области (ее тоже можно изменять)
2. Координаты вершин
3. Список ребер с их длинами и указанием вершин, которые они соединяют

Кажется, что я не смог найти нормальной библиотеки, которая может удовлетворить моим запросам, поэтому, видимо, придется писать это самому. Мои умения по проектированию графических приложений ограничиваются созданием не очень сложных WinForms-приложений, поэтому я прошу вас указать мне направление для изучения (возможно, в WPF есть что-то, что может мне помочь).

Comment: Это можно сделать хоть на WinForms, хоть на WPF. Но вам придётся всё писать вручную — вершины рисовать кружочками, рёбра линиями, при перетаскивании точки перерисовывать все идущие в неё линии  и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

На github есть проект [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout) ([MSAGL](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/)), который позволяет создавать графы в WinForms, например, такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По этой ссылке: https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/programma-dlya-postroeniya-grafov.html
прилично написанная программа для рисования графов. Я на ее базе делал пример построения графа видимости и алгоритма дейкстры. Имея небольшую сноровку Вы сможете добавить туда необходимые Вам функции. Я бы рекомендовал использовать Winforms. Как мне кажется, они все же попроще. Не нужно вдаваться в xaml.